# Energy Consumption Data Filter by time

Tags: grafana, influxdb, energy

I am new to Grafana and I would like to know if there is any way to filter the data that the Grafana by the time it has, example: I am plotting energy consumption data and I would like to see only the energy data from 2 PM to 5 PM of my whole week. There is any way to do it?

Comment: What data source are you using?

Comment: I'm Using Influx db

Comment: I don't know influx, but it sounds like something you'll solve with InfluxQL rather than with Grafana. If you do, you can replicate the solving query in the datasource metrics editor.